# Show views like tabs in list view web part

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-server, list-view

I have about 8 custom views in list , I need to show this views as Tabs with a specific order

```
View1 View2 View3 View4 View5 View6 View7 View8
----------------------------------------------------
Title Name
```

I need any css code to show the view title as Tabs and show all views without this more points **...**

Any help !! Thanks

Comment: which version of sharepoint ?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not direct way to achieve this..one way is that you would need to do custom coding to get all the views on list, use some tab framework to create tabs using this list of views and display views... There are some scripts read available for this, below might get you started. Basically you need to add List view webparts of list on one page and follow below steps mentioned...

[Link 1](http://www.markrackley.net/2013/04/24/tabbed-web-parts-in-sharepoint-2013-office-365/)
[Link 2](http://www.markrackley.net/2015/08/16/sharepoint-tabbed-web-partshillbillytabs-3-0/)

To use the scripts, follow these steps:

Upload the above script to a location you can reference in your site (like possibly the Site Assets Document Library)

Create a Web Part Page.

Add the various Web Parts onto the page that you want to appear in the tabbed view.

Add a Content Editor Web Part to the page.

Edit the above script so that the call to the “HillbillyTabs” function contains the titles of the Web Parts you wish to appear in the tabbed view. For instance. If you had a Web Part with the title “Projects” and another Web Part with the title “Tasks”, the section of script you would change would look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        HillbillyTabs(["Projects","Tasks"]);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , where i should set the views name ?

Comment: In your list view webpart property settings.